# Only dead fish "go" or "goes"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, uncountable-nouns

In the following quote, why does it use "go" instead of "goes"?

> Only dead fish **go** with the flow. Don't be a dead fish!

Comment: One fish, two fish, all fish.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey red fish, blue fish?

Comment: But one can be unfortunate enough to sleep with fishes, and not in a fun way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here fish used is in plural form, because plural form of fish is fish. When there are multiple fish and of the species we use the word fish for them. That is why **go** is used. But in the second part fish is in singular form